# Ubuntu 15.10 unable to detect all CPUs

Tags: 15.10, cpu

lscpu lists the following

```
 venki@venki-H8DCL:~$ lscpu
 Architecture:          x86_64
 CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
 Byte Order:            Little Endian
 CPU(s):                12
 On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
 Thread(s) per core:    2
 Core(s) per socket:    3   <------ I have 6 cores
 Socket(s):             2
 NUMA node(s):          2
 Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
 CPU family:            21
 Model:                 2
 Model name:            AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4334
 Stepping:              0
 CPU MHz:               1400.000
 CPU max MHz:           3100.0000
 CPU min MHz:           1400.0000
 BogoMIPS:              6199.90
 Virtualization:        AMD-V
 L1d cache:             16K
 L1i cache:             64K
 L2 cache:              2048K
 L3 cache:              6144K
 NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-5
 NUMA node1 CPU(s):     6-11
```

Comment: I have 12 cpu cores. It is a 6 core processor and I have two of them. I can see them in BIOS.  This processor doesn't support hyper-threading so 12 physical cores should to be detected.

Answer (score 3):

[AMD's specs](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/CPU/AMD-Opteron%E2%84%A2/AMD-Opteron%E2%84%A2-4300-Series-Processor/4334/11) indicate that CPU is six cores and six threads, but you're seeing three cores with two threads each.

Combine that with what appears to be a dual-socket board and your total "CPU count" (4th line), and it does appear to be detecting them all, it's just not displaying the totals the way you expect.

Comment: You are correct. It effects my parallel programs which looks for physical cores rather than logical cores.

Answer (score 0):

According to the 4th line you have 12 CPU(s).

Maybe you are looking for this information:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```